# Table Per Subclass Vs Table Per concrete class in hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate

In most of the web application, i have seen  one base class consisting common properties and number of subclasses extending base class . So my question here is which strategy we should go for among **Table Per Subclass Vs Table Per concrete class**. I personally feel we should go for table per subclass because in future if we want to introduce the common column we can do it at one place but in case of concrete class we have to do it in multiple tables. **Right?**

But yes if we  want to fetch all deatils from all child tables i think **Table per concrete class** will be helpful Because we have to simply union the records from all tables but in case of **Table per Sub class** along with union we have to introduce the join with parent table which will be extra costlier .**Right?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might be interested in Section 2.12 "Inheritance Mapping Strategies" of the [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-javadocs.zip), as it sums up all possbible inheritance types as well as their advantages and drawbacks. Let me pull out just the most interesting fragments:

**2.12.1 Single Table per Class Hierarchy Strategy**

> This mapping strategy provides good support for **polymorphic**
>   relationships between entities and for queries that range over the
>   class hierarchy. It has the drawback, however, that it requires that
>   the columns that correspond to state specific to the subclasses be
>   **nullable**.

**2.12.3 Table per Concrete Class Strategy**

> This strategy has the following drawbacks:
>   - It provides **poor** support for polymorphic relationships.
>   - It typically requires that **SQL UNION** queries (or a separate SQL query per subclass) be issued for queries that are intended to range over the class hierarchy.

**2.12.2 Joined Subclass Strategy**

> It has the drawback that it requires that **one or more join operations**
>   be performed to instantiate instances of a subclass. In deep class
>   hierarchies, this may lead to **unacceptable performance**. Queries that
>   range over the class hierarchy likewise require joins.

Also, if you're planning to be JPA-compatible, remember that the JPA-provider **doesn't have to** support `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy type.

---

> I personally feel we should go for table per subclass because in
>   future if we want to introduce the common column we can do it at one
>   place but in case of concrete class we have to do it in multiple
>   tables.

True, but JOINED strategy also provides you the same feature and allows to specify common properties in one table.

Hope that helps!

Comment: hi Piotr,Thanks for reply.Can you throw some light on how  Single Table per Class Hierarchy Strategy provides good support for polymorphic but Joined Subclass Strategy does not.

Comment: @MohitGupta well this is how I see it: assume you have a `Animal -> [Dog, Cat]` hierarchy. In `singleTable` you have all types in one table - no need to do joins when someone executes `SELECT Animal a...`. If you have `joinedStrategy` than you need to do JOINs on the tables (as each subclass is in the different table), but still you have a common attributes in one table (Animal). However, in the `concreteTable` strategy each class is in the separate table, so selecting all animals will require to access all of the tables separately. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Piotr.Agreed with clarification.But how it is related with polymorphism here.. I am bit skeptical about the word polymorphism.

Comment: Well, you're asking for `Animal` instances and you don't care what subclass of it will be returned. You can even filter it using some common attributes for `Animal` - once again you don't care what subclasses will be returned. This is what is called a `polymorphic query`.

Comment: Also, in case of not-only-jpa, table per hierarchy level strategy allows you to use a mutable subclassing of your entities.

Comment: What about Joined?

Answer (score 19):

**[The Object-Relational Impedance Mismatch](http://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/)**

*In Object Model, while creating object we may require to use inheritance i.e. Generalization as follows:*

[image]

[image]

---

In Relational Model, **the above Generalization(not association i.e. one-to-one or many-to-many) can achieve in Hibernate ORM with the following three inheritance mapping strategies:**

- Table Per Class i.e. for Hierarchy only one table
- Table Per Concrete class i.e. One table for each concrete class not for super class
- Table Per Subclass i.e. One table fore each class

[image]

*In this strategy, we can map the whole hierarchy into single table, here we use one more discriminator column i.e. TYPE.*

---

[image]

In this strategy, tables are created as per class but related by foreign key. So there are no duplicate columns.

---

[image]

In this strategy, tables are created as per class but related by foreign key. So there are no duplicate columns.

---

[image]

[image source](http://way2java.com/hibernate/differences-between-table-per-class-table-per-subclass-table-per-concreteclass/)

Comment: What about Joined?